# knitr: Can a child access files from a higher directory in master/child setup

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I am having trouble with the knitr master child setup.

How can the child access files in a higher directory? For example if I have a file structure with the following files

./images/photo.jpg

./master.Rnw

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\begin{document}
<<blah, child='./child/child.Rnw'>>=
@

\end{document}
```

./child/child.Rnw

```
<<echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
  set_parent('../master.Rnw')
@

\includegraphics{photo.jpg}
```

The problem I have is that child.Rnw does not compile properly but master.Rnw does.

If I change \includegraphics{photo.jpg} to \includegraphics{../images/photo.jpg} and remove \graphicspath from the master the opposite occurs: the child compiles, but the master does not.

Aside from duplicating ./images into ./child, is there a way to resolve this problem?

Thank you.